# Difference between LL parser and AST

Tags: parsing, grammar, abstract-syntax-tree, ll-grammar

I'm currently trying to create an LL parser.
However I already have my BNF grammar but I have to create before an AST and I have a few question.

- What's the difference between an AST and an LL parser ?
  (Because both of them are a binary tree)
- How can I create an AST from BNF grammar ?
  (
  http://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2009/02/05/evaluating-expressions-part-3-building-the-ast/

I found on google this tutorial which explain a lot about build an AST otherwise, they don't explain how to know if I have to take the right branch or the left branch.)

Thank's

Answer (score 2):

An AST is an abstract syntax tree - it's a tree that encodes the logical structure of the program that was provided as input to the compiler. Typically, the job of the compiler front-end is to build an AST for the input program and annotate it with helpful information that the optimizer and code generator can then use to produce the output program.

Typically, the part of the compiler that actually generates the AST is called the **parser**. There are many different classes of parser, of which the **LL** parsers are one popular family. LL parsers can often be hand-written, but they're often generated automatically using compiler generation tools.

In other words, the answer to your main question of what the difference between an AST and an LL parser is is "an LL parser is a type of parser, and a parser is something that generates an AST."

Your next question was how you build an AST from a BNF grammar. Typically, you wouldn't build an AST for a BNF grammar itself. Instead, the grammar would guide the construction of the parser, and the parser would then build the AST. Actually building a parser is usually a topic covered in a standard compilers course. If you're interested, [I have a set of lecture slides available from the last time I taught a compilers class](http://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs143/cs143.1128/), and lectures 02, 03, and 04 cover syntax analysis and how to design and build LL parsers. Hopefully they give you a push in the right direction!

Comment: Readers: I've looked at the course slides.  They' re very good.